# Unable to find new refreshed frame from webdriver and then find an element to it

Tags: selenium

I am very new to selenium. I am trying to automate my EMS/NMS test cases.
Test environment: My webpage is actually an application for NMS operations[it is a private webpage]. Now source of the main page is:

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset bordercolor="gray" border="3" rows="10%,90%">
<frame scrolling="no" bordercolor="black" src="/cgi-bin/portal.cgi" noborder="" name="start_tab">
<html>
   <head>
      <body bgcolor="white">
         <style type="text/css">
|
            <a target="showcase" href="/Portal/sonm/cgi-bin/welcome">Ckt</a>
|
           <a target="showcase" href="/cgi-bin/build_instpage">EM Inst</a>
|
           <a target="showcase" href="/Portal/BAT/cgi-bin/bat_welcome.pl">System Check</a>
|
            <a target="showcase" href="/Portal/SOEM-GUI/cgi-bin/soem_welcome">EM</a>
|
         </body>
      </html>
    </frame>
```

Now from the above, I am able to click on "EM" which is on the first frame called "start_tab" when I click on this, another page is not opened, instead second frame is refreshed and a login button appears. Now I need to access this login button. However, I am not able to locate this login button. Src code for this is:

```
<script language="Javascript">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td width="100%" align="center">
              <table>
                 <tbody>
                       <tr>
                          <td width="100%" align="center">
                              <a href="http://actual button">
                                 <img style="< border="" src="http://login_btn.png">
                               </a>
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                </tbody>
           </table>
```

I have tried, xpath for the button, I have tried by tag name, but I think I am not able to go to this new refreshed frame. Also when I fetch source-code I get the source code of previous frame.

Just to add, entire page is divided into two pages:
1) start_tab which has all the links
2) showcase which will be refreshed with content depending on the link clicked.

Also is there any good documentation apart from JavaDocs for webdrvier wherein different web app testing scenarios are discussed.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to frame before locating the button

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); // you are now outside of current frame  
driver.switchTo().frame("start_tab");
// now add code to locate login button
```

Comment: @Karna-Thanks! but I did the same thing, for start_tab, frame does not refresh, but when I click on the link, the second frame refreshes, and when I switch to that I am not able to locate "button".

Comment: @user3543782 Is it a nested frame? Add some relevant HTML

Comment: @Karna-With default content switch I am able to switch to showCase! Thanks a lot, then with xpath I am able to find my button and click on it.

Comment: @Karna-I am sorry,but couldn't find accepted tab anywhere.